# Overlap between Python and C++ references

Tags: python, c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a question about references in c++ and its overlap to python. I have written a function in python that takes in x and y and adds y to x. Thereafter, I print the outcome.

```
def func(x, y):
    x = x + y
    return x

c = [5,4,6,4]
d = [6,7,8,9]
t = func(c,d)
print(t)
print(c)
```

As python passes everything by reference, one would expect that the variable c would change and contain d. However, this is not the case.
To see if this also holds true for c++, I have written a vector function that adds two vectors together.

```
vector<int> FuncAdd(vector<int> &x, vector<int> &y){

x.insert(x.end(), y.begin(), y.end());

return x;
}

int main(){
vector<int> y = {3,4,5,6};
vector<int> x = {4,5,6,7};
vector<int> c = FuncAdd(x, y);

for(int i : x){  
    cout << i << " ";
}
cout << endl;
for(int i : c){  
    cout << i << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

The outcome here is that x does change and now contains y. Why does c++ change the vector and python does not change its list? Thanks!

Comment: Because they are 2 different languages. They behaves differently. Also in python it is more likely acts as a pointer not a reference. So you are not changing c. It should be something like: `def func(x, y): \ [x.append(i) for i in y]` then you actually change c.

Comment: That explains it, thanks!

Comment: "As python passes everything by reference" Python *never*, *ever* passes *anything* by reference. Here's a challange: write a function, `swap(x, y)` that in will swap two variables in *any context*, e.g. `a = 0, b = 99; swap(a, b); print(a, b)` would print `99 0` instead of `0 99`. You can't. But this is trivially possible in a language that supports call by reference (like C++ does). Note, Python is also not call by value, since arguments to a function are not copied

Comment: Read the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 2):

In Python, when you use `+` for *concatenating* two lists **a new list is created and returned**. This means that when you wrote `x + y`, a new list is created. This also means that after `x = x + y`, the local variable `x` will now refer to the newly created list(as a result of `x + y`). If you want to change the original list **in-place** you could instead use the `extend` method as explained in the below example.

```
#--------v--v------------->x and y are local variables that refer to the passed objects
def func(x, y):
    
#-------vvvvv------------->this x + y creates a new list
    x = x + y
#---^--------------------->the "local variable x" on the left hand side now refers to the new list object created as a result of x + y
    return x

c = [5,4,6,4]
d = [6,7,8,9]


t = func(c,d) #here t refers to the object returned by the call to func which essentially was created from x + y 
print(t)      #prints the object return by the call to func [5, 4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(c)      #prints c which still refers to the original list [5, 4, 6, 4]
```

---

Note instead of writing `x = x + y` and then returning `x` you could just have written `return x + y` and the effect will be the same, as shown below:

```
#--------v--v------------->x and y are local variables that refer to the passed objects
def func(x, y):

    return x +y #creates and returns a new list object

c = [5,4,6,4]
d = [6,7,8,9]


t = func(c,d) #here t refers to the object returned by the call to func which essentially was created from x + y 
print(t)      #prints the object return by the call to func [5, 4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(c)      #prints c which still refers to the original list [5, 4, 6, 4]
```

---

If you want to change the original list **in-place** you can use list's `extend` method as shown below:

```
#--------v--v------------->x and y are local variables that refer to the passed objects
def func(x, y):
#-----vvvvvv-------------->changes x in-place instead of creating a new list
    x.extend(y); 

c = [5,4,6,4]
d = [6,7,8,9]

#no need to do the assignment here because the changes made to the list inside func will be reflected in the original list as we have used extend method
func(c,d) 
print(c)      #prints c [5, 4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

Similarly, in C++ you're using the `std::vector::insert` member function of `std::vector` that will insert the elements into the vector on which the member function was called(which is the vector `x`). And since you've passed the vector `x` by reference, the change will be reflected in the original vector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's true, in Python when you call a function you get a reference to the same object that was in the caller.  If you modify that object, you'll see that modification after the function returns.

But the statement `x = x + y` does *not* modify `x`, it creates a brand new reference `x` that replaces the old one from that point of the function onwards.

Answer (score 0):

In python Object references are passed by value.

So your list is an object [5,4,6,4] and you gave it the name 'c'

When you pass variable c to a function, the object is passed by value but it will be the same object.

So x is a different variable but contains the same object, until...

You assign x with another object
i.e. x+y
Now x has a different object, not the same as what c has

Thats why, append() would work because it is essentially an operation on the same object.

Refer to below link if it is still unclear
[Python pass by value or reference](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)